# Can I change the default escaping in Handlebars.java?

Tags: java, templates, handlebars.java

I have a template with default Handlebars expansion `{{thing}}`.

For various nasty reasons I'd like to use it to render JSON, and so not to do the default HTML escaping that comes with `{{`.

I'd also like to use the template in an HTML context.

Can I set up a Handlebars.java instance with different default escaping behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure Handlebars with various `EscapingStrategy`s - in this case `EscapingStrategy.JS` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you can because you are using handlebars.java. By default, standard implementation of handlebars don't allow it.

as you can see on [this issue](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java/issues/303), the code that you must use is this:

```
Handlebars hbs = new Handlebars()
    .startDelimiter("<%")
    .endDelimiter("%>");
```

Comment: Ah, maybe I wasn't clear. I don't want to change the delimiters - they're fine. I want to change the escaping of the template output.

Comment: oh, sorry. change the escaping of all template output? i think that the decorators can help, or no?